# how to write on each curve in a Matlab Plot

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data that I'm trying to analyse using the `pwelch` function of Matlab , my problem is that I have 13 curves and I get more , I want to label each curves, so i can deffirenciate between them, I tried  using legend, but it didn't help . 
here is my code and the result that I get:

```
  clear, clc , clf;
M = 512;
k = 1
hold all;
grid on ;
for i =1:13
    pause(2)
    fileName =['M',int2str(i),'.wav']
       [x,fs] = audioread(fileName);
     [xPSD,f]  = pwelch(x,hann(2048),1024,2048*4 ,fs);
     plot(f,10*log10(xPSD))
     text(7,30,fileName);
    xlim([0 15e3]);
    Leg{i} =['qho-',num2str(i)];
end
legend(Leg)
```

[image: the result]

thanks for your help!

Comment: What's wrong with your legend? How exactly do you want these labels to look?

Comment: Do you want the labels closer to the lines (instead of being grouped in a legend box)? That might appear to be a fix, however, you have a lot of lines in that plot already - it's not going to become any better. Do you need all these lines, individually labeled, in one plot?

Comment: @Schorsch yes that will be perfect

Comment: @Dan qho-12 and qho-5 look the same  10 and 3  also etc .. #

Comment: Again - how about taking a step back? You have a lot of lines and are expecting to get more. Is this plot - where a lot of the lines are very close to each other - helpful to your cause? The colors will become very similar, curves will be difficult to distinguish, etc. I'm not sure if labels close to the curve are really solving your issue.

Comment: well , I'll  zoom  some areas , that why I would like to label each one apart !

Comment: Maybe [this portion of the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/how-to-annotate-graphs.html) gets you started. (You can see the code behind what you did if you choose 'generate code' for the figure)

Comment: I've already read that ! thanks !

Comment: You might also want to use this submission from the File Exchange: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors

Comment: @am304 , it sound interestnig but how can  I use it in my plots ?

Comment: @Engine to avoid having the same colour used twice. In your case, `colors = distinguishable_colors(13)` will generate 13 different colours that you can use for each of your 13 lines.

Comment: you can separate them a bit using something like this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24368-stacked-plot

Comment: offtopic, but can't help myself: +1 for a question about spectral estimation that uses a spectral estimation function (`pwelch`) and not some homegrown stuff involving `fft`.